# How to loop in template over serializer used as form

Tags: django, forms, rest, serialization

I need a CRUD-table and don't want to write out the field names (too many). I want use the serializer to make the forms in the first row and the already entered data in the rows below.  Displaying the data works fine, even with choices and FK. The problem is that i cannot loop over the form-fields.

In "template1.html" I checked "render_form" and the serializer. Ok, so far. PROBLEM: In "template2.hmtl" I try to **loop** and position each form (rendered REST serializer) in a column and get errors. How to loop correctly?

```
template1.html
...rest of table is omitted...

     <tr>
        <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}

              <th>
                   {% render_form serializer template_pack='rest_framework/inline'%}
                        <input type="submit" value="Save">
              </th>

        </form>
     </tr>
```

```
template2.html
...rest of table is omitted...

     <tr>
        <form method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {% for s in serializer %}         
              <th>
                   {% render_form s template_pack='rest_framework/inline'%}

              </th>
           {% endfor %}
              <th>
                  <input type="submit" value="Save">
              </th>
        </form>
     </tr>
```

**The Error:** I get is " ...Error during template redering...", "Exception Value:
'CharField' object has no attribute 'data'". It seams that "serializer" is not iterable. I tried also {% for s in serializer.data %} in the template.

**Additinal Information:**

```
serializer.py

class MyChoiceField(serializers.ChoiceField):
    ''' for display of field labels not keys'''

    def to_representation(self, data):
        if data not in self.choices.keys():
            self.fail('invalid_choice', input=data)
        else:
            return self.choices[data]

class KernSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
    # strassenorientierung = serializers.SerializerMethodField(style={'base_template': 'select.html'})
    strassenorientierung = MyChoiceField(choices=Kern.CHOICES_strassenorientierung)
    oberflachenzustand   = MyChoiceField(choices=Kern.CHOICES_oberflachenzustand)
    beregnung            = MyChoiceField(choices=Kern.CHOICES_beregnung)
    date_posted = serializers.DateTimeField(format=None, default_timezone=TIME_ZONE) #format=DATETIME_FORMAT)
    class Meta:
        # 'url',
        model = Kern
        fields = ['url', 'id','abstand_horiz', 'abstand_vert', 'abstand_fahrtricht', 'strassenorientierung', 'oberflachenzustand','beregnung','entnahme_datum', 'betondeckung', 'bohrkernbezeichnung', 'karbonatisierung', 'wennersonde', 'comment','date_posted']
        depth = 1


view.py:

...stuff deleted ...
    serializer = KernSerializer()
     content = {'serializer': serializer, 'objekt_form': objekt_form, 'objektebelow': objektebelow_DRF.data, 'form': form, 'fields_list_displayed': fields_list_displayed, 'form_fields':form_fields,'model':model, 'next_url':next_url, 'projekt': projekt, 'objekt_data': objekt_data, 'projekt_id':projekt_id, 'objekt_id': objekt_id, 'bauteil': bauteil}
     return render(request, template_name, content)
```

Comment: Can you include the errors you're getting?

Comment: now included...